# Go: display array in array with templates

Tags: go

How do I insert a variable in a Go template like this - I have this code in HTML:

```
{{define "homepage"}}
<html>
<form action="/home/delete" method="POST">
    {{with .Posts}}
        {{range .}} 
            <p id="twt">{{ range $i := .Status}}{{$i}}<br><br></p>
            <button type="submit" id="xbutton" name="xdel" value="{{.Tweetid}}">Delete</button>
            {{end}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
</form>
</html>
{{end}}
```

The code in Go:

```
type User struct {
    Userid      int64
    Username    string
    Password    string
    Posts       []*Post
}

type Post struct {
    Tweetid     int
    Username    string
    Status      []string
}

func deletehandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    currentuser = getUserName(r)
    postvalue = r.PostFormValue("xdel")
    DeleteTweet() 
    if currentuser != "" {
        as := Post{Username: currentuser, Status: ReadStatus(), Tweetid: ReadStatusId()}
        person := User{Username: currentuser, Posts: []*Post{&as}}
        t := template.Must(template.New("tele").ParseFiles("layout/home.html"))
            if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "homepage", person); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    } else {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
    }
}

//getting the .Tweetid
func ReadStatusId() (res int) {
    //some code to open and access the sql database
    rows, _ := db.Query("Select id from posts where tweet = ?", AddTweet)
    some code for error handling
    defer rows.Close()

    var status string
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&status)
        if err != nil {
           fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("this %s", status)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    (//code for other handlers..)
    router.HandleFunc("/home/delete", deletehandler).Methods("POST")
}
```

However, the error message I get is

```
can't evaluate field Tweetid in type string
```

How do I fix this and allow .Tweetid to be read in the value string? If this helps I referred to this for the way I've used the templates: http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html

Comment: you're probably rendering the template wrong. can you post more complete code?

Comment: ok edited. I didn't post Go code though. I think the error is in the html because when I replaced {{.Tweetid}} with an integer, it works just fine.

Comment: And of what type was `Tweetid` *before* you replaced it?

Comment: of type integer. I meant I edited the code to be - value="4", for example, instead of value="{{.Tweetid}}

Comment: Please post the Go code you are using. The dot value in the `range` loop appears to be of type `string`, which does not have a field `Tweetid`.

Comment: Ok I've added the relevant Go code. Hope it makes things clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the template:

```
{{range $p := .Posts}} 
   <p id="twt">{{ range $i := .Status}}{{$i}}<br><br></p>
   <button type="submit" id="xbutton" name="xdel" value="{{$p.Tweetid}}">Delete</button>
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```

using `{{.Tweetid}}` inside the `{{ range $i := ... }}` would reference `{{$i.Tweetid}}` adding `range $p := .Posts}}` and referencing it  explicitly with `{{$p.Tweetid}}` will solve the problem

Comment: I know what you mean. Nothing happens when I click on the button though, with this solution. Let me work on it later.